# Qt ISO C++ forbids declaration without type - header file is included?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm receiving the forbids declaration without type error in a Qt application I'm working on.  The problem is that I have included the header file which declares the class.  It should be defined as a type as far as I can tell.  I tried forward declaration as well, but I'd like to use the methods of the class in this file and so I need the whole header file.
code:

Shapes.h

```
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

#include "Colors.h"
#include <QPoint>
#include "glwidget.h"

//class GLWidget;  

class Shape
{
    public:

        virtual void draw();
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
    public:
        Rectangle(GLWidget *w, QPoint tl, QPoint br);

        virtual void draw(){
              // top horizontal
            for(int i = topLeft.x(); i < btmRight.x(); i++){
                 glWidget->setPixel(i,topLeft.y(), color);
             }
        }

    private:
        QPoint topLeft,btmRight;
        GLWidget *glWidget;        /****  This is the Error line  ****/
        RGBColor color;
};

#endif // SHAPES_H
```

glwidget.h:

```
#ifndef AGLWIDGET_H
#define AGLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

#include "Colors.h"
#include "Shapes.h"

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

    void setPixel(int x, int y, RGBColor c);

public slots:
    void setColor(RGBColor c);
    void setDrawRectangle();



protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:

    QPoint lastPos;
    QVector<QPoint> drawPoints;
    RGBColor paintColor;
    int drawmode;
    Shape *currentShape;

};


#endif
```

I don't see why I can't use my GLWidget in Shapes.h.  The error is in Shapes.h on the line where I declare GLWidget *glWidget;
If I use a forward declaration ie. class GLWidget; this error goes away but then I can't actually use the GLWidget methods as in Rectangle.draw()

Anyone have an idea why the compiler wouldn't see GLWidget as a type in Shapes.h?

Exact errors:

Shapes.h:20: error: expected ')' before '*' token
Shapes.h:31: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'GLWidget' with no type
Shapes.h:31: error: expected ';' before '*' token
Shapes.h: In member function 'virtual void Rectangle::draw()':
Shapes.h:25: error: 'glWidget' undeclared (first use this function)
Shapes.h:25: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

Comment: This is C++ specific, and probably shouldn't be tagged C.

Comment: shapes includes glwidget and glwidget includes shapes. Is that correct?

Comment: @pmg: If it is, it won't work.  Shapes.h prevents itself from being included a second time, so the #include in glwidget.h won't include anything.

Comment: yes they include eachother.  I have macro include guards for each header so it shouldn't cause an infinite loop

Comment: ahhh  Ok...  so how do I get GLWidget included in shapes.h and shapes.h included in GLWidget then?

Comment: One will be included in the other, but both won't be able to include each other -- one of the includes will effectively include nothing -- so any types in one won't be available in the other without a forward declaration somewhere, or some clever #define ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between your header files -- Shapes.h includes glwidget.h, which includes Shapes.h again.  So, the second time the compiler tries to include glwidget.h, the include guard `AGLWIDGET_H` *has* been defined, so it doesn't include it again, and then the code in Shapes.h tries to use types that ought to have been declared but are not.

To fix it, you need to remove one of the dependencies and use forward declarations instead.  Since glwidget.h doesn't actually use the `Shape` class beyond declaring a pointer member variable, you should remove its inclusion of Shapes.h:

glwidget.h:

```
#ifndef AGLWIDGET_H
#define AGLWIDGET_H

// do NOT include Shapes.h

class Shape;  // forward declaration

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    ...
    Shape *currentShape;
};

#endif
```

Shapes.h is the same as before:

```
#ifndef SHAPES_H
#define SHAPES_H

#include "glwidget.h"
...
#endif
```

Comment: This solves the current situation, but the code provided is not a complete implementation.  GLWidget WILL need to know methods of Shape classes.  There must be some way for me to have them included in both?

Comment: hmm actually I suppose just glwidget.cpp needs to actually know the methods of Shape classes so I can include Shapes.h in glwidget.cpp?

Comment: @wallacer: Yes, glwidget.cpp needs to include Shapes.h, but that's ok because it doesn't create a circular dependency (since nothing includes glwidget.cpp).

Comment: great thanks for the help, can't believe this is the first time I've run into this!

Comment: I'd recommend moving the Shape class into its own header file (since really, it's probably just an interface anyway), and renaming Shapes.h to Rectangle.h.  Then you can include shape.h from both files without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the include order - you use a circular inclusion and only the include guards prevent you from looping the compiler.
You can resolve this in your particular case by forward-declaring the shape class in glWidget.h and removing the include for Shapes.h:

```
//#include "Shapes.h"
class Shape;
```